# Determine location of volume buttons

Tags: android

Is there any way to get the location (x,y) of the volume buttons?

WearOS has this, which only gives a general idea and of course is limited to Android watches
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/physical-buttons

I'd like to mark the buttons in a certain screen.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, AFAIK this is not supplied by the Android SDK for other Android devices.